# Expandable table

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, jquery-selectors

I want to make expandable table like this [expandable table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfZGa.png) filled by PHP script. Now it doesn't work after i added if statement in hidden.foreach(). Do You know why it doesn't work and how to fix this problem ?

```
echo "<table><thead><th>Product</th><th>Expenses</th><th>Group</th><th>Show more</th></thead>";
    while($row=$show_costs->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $show_more_costs=$conn->query("SELECT `name`,`describtion`,`cost`,`b_date`,`group` FROM `costs` WHERE `pId`='".$row['pId']."'");
        echo "<tr><td>".$row['pId']."</td><td>".$row['costs']."</td><td>".$$row['group']."</td><td><span id='show_more'>▼</span></td></tr>";
        //Detailed costs which i want to expand after clicking this
        while($row_md=$show_more_costs->fetch_assoc())
        {
            echo "<tr class='hidden'><td>".$row_md['name']."</td><td>".$row_md['describtion']."</td><td>".$row_md['cost']."</td><td>".$row_md['b_date']."</td><td>".$row_md['group']."</td></tr>";
        }
    }
    echo "</table>";
```

//This is my JS code:

```
show_more=document.querySelectorAll('#show_more');
hidden=document.querySelectorAll('.hidden');
show_more.forEach(show_more =>{
  show_more.addEventListener('click',event=>{
    hidden.forEach(hidden=>{
      if(hidden.style.display==='none')
      {
        hidden.style.display='table-row';
      }
      if(hidden.style.display==='table-row')
      {
        h1.style.display='none';
      }
    })
  })
})
```

What do I have to fix?

Comment: Already changed

Comment: What does "does not work" mean?  Errors in the console? Wrong thing happening? Site crashes? Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question to contain a proper and detailed description of your issue. Also include what debugging you've done.

Comment: One problem I see in your code is `id='show_more'` in your loop. This will generate multiple elements with the same ID. That's not valid in HTML. All ID's _must_ be unique within a document. No elements can share the same.

Comment: You also seem to have a typo: `".$$row['group']."` (one `$` too many)